# How do I simulate a proper sinewave in LTSpice? Setting a voltage source to SINE(X Y Z) is not quite a sine wave

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I have a very simple simulation. Just a voltage source set to an 80v DC offset with an amplitude of 2 volts and frequency of 1500Hz. Unfortunately, LTSpice doesn't seem to be capable of simulating a sine wave. Am I doing something wrong here?

I have seen other people produce sine waves using LTSpice, so I'm pretty sure it's possible. What's going on here?

I tried putting a resistor across it, but no change.

[image: Sine wave on LTSpice]

[image]
I even tried lowering the frequency, but now the results are much worse.
[image: There are even some major glitches]

I have tried restarting the program, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Your parameters are in the wrong order.
It should be...
Sine(2 80 1500)
V(Offset) = 2
V = 80
Freq = 1500

Comment: @GTElectronics As I commented before you deleted your answer and changed it to a comment, my parameters are not in the wrong order.

Comment: Did you change the integration settings etc. ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try .option plotwinsize=0

Always good to try when you get weird waveforms like that.

Likely compression/sampling issue.
[image]

Comment: That worked! How does this work to fix compression issues?

Comment: LTspice uses compression and downsampling to minimize memory file sizes and processing time by default. As you've seen, it can result in bad waveforms, similar to aliasing. This option disables it.

Comment: @griffin175 Don't forget that disabling compression means the `.raw` file will grow and can reach GB, or more, depending on the case. In that case, the `.SAVE` can help, because with many variables to write the disk write bandwidth can be reached or exceeded, which means the simulation will go slow.

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate the difference between OP and @pat 's solution, I exported the waveforms as text. Here are the first fifty points. Without the `plotwinsize=0` option, these points span several cycles as shown in the red with a jagged appearance.

**EDIT**

[image]

File details:

- Without the option, 20154 lines
- With the option, 44360 lines

Answer (score 0):

If you need a user-defined source (i.e. not a normal sine source) in the future, you can also insert a `VPWL_FILE` from the library and have it point to the text file. You can write a program that creates a text file and writes a few values into it (English notation, 2 columns: `Time` `TAB` `a Value`).